# If I have two 2670 Xeon srokx processors does it have the same stepping?

Tags: central-processing-unit, xeon

If I have 2670 Xeon SROKX processors does it have the same stepping? (the processor picture attached) Is srokx the stepping number? I want to use two of these processors in a dual socket motherboard. Most of the websites have stated that I should have identical processors with identical stepping number to use the processors in dual socket motherboard. If srokx is not the stepping number, what is the stepping number of the processor attached (if it's printed on the processor)

[image]

Comment: AFAIK CPU's with the **same model number** (in this case  [E5-2670](http://ark.intel.com/products/64595/Intel-Xeon-Processor-E5-2670-20M-Cache-2_60-GHz-8_00-GTs-Intel-QPI) ) will always have the the same features

Comment: @HBruijn you say that stepping number has nothing to do with when using a dual socket motherboard as long as the model numbers are same? that's strange.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`SR0KX` is indeed the stepping number, but that is not something you really need to worry about as the [product sheet](http://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/processors/xeon/xeon-e5-1600-2600-vol-1-datasheet.html) states about mixing CPU's:

> Mixing
>   processors of *different steppings* but the **same model** (as per CPUID instruction) is
>   supported provided there is no more than one stepping delta between the processors,
>   for example, S and S+1.

And with regards to that caveat; I don't recall that ever being an issue with server CPU's with the same model number and specifically : the [product documentation](http://ark.intel.com/products/64595/Intel-Xeon-Processor-E5-2670-20M-Cache-2_60-GHz-8_00-GTs-Intel-QPI) also states that only two 2 steppings (C1 and C2) were made for the Xeon E5-2670  CPU:

[image: CPU steppings for E5-2670]

Comment: Two steppings were made for retail `C1 (QBF5, SR0H8)` and `C2 (QBV7, SR0KX)`, but there is an additional engineering sample `C0 (QB7A)` according to [cpu-world.com](http://www.cpu-world.com/CPUs/Xeon/Intel-Xeon%20E5-2670.html). Engineering samples usually have an **sSpec** starting with `Q`.

Comment: ohh, great, so the SROKX is the stepping number C2, since my two processors have srokx printed on the surface, I think I'll have no problem at all.